# Ubuntu 14.04 - Qt version choosing

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04

I mistakenly updated my qt version from 4.8.5 to 4.8.6. This happened as a result of python anaconda installation.

However I am working on a project that needs qt 4.8.5.

Running `qmake -v` shows:

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in home/<username>/anaconda/lib
```

How do I switch to my previous qt version (installed in the default directory, i.e. /usr/... )?

`qtchooser` lists the following options:

```
$ qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

But trying `export QT_SELECT` with every option didn't change the message:

```
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in home/<username>/anaconda/lib
```

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Aren't they compatible?  What's the issue?

Comment: @trojanfoe Apparrently Qt4.8.6 is incompatible with some other libraries that the project uses.

Comment: @Nfys isn't that a bug in the other library?

Comment: What is the result of running `echo $PATH` from a terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use several versions of Qt. All you need to do is - call `qmake`, that comes with the needed version. For example:

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin/qmake -v
```

When using `QtCreator`, you can add Qt version in `Tools/Options.../Build & Run` and switch between Qt versions in project's settings (some versions on `QtCreator` will require creating a Kit also, which is not very hard).

The only problem I faced is - using `cmake` (hate this piece of garbage). In this case you'll need to change the order in which `qmake` of different versions are called. First of all, find out where your default `qmake` is located (`which qmake`), then - whether it is a symlink or not (it is strange, that Qt, installed in your home directory is called without using full path). If it is a link, then change it from one Qt's version to another. If not - examine `echo $PATH`. What you can do: you can create a symlink for Qt4.8.5's `qmake` to a directory, which is previous to one, in which Qt4.8.6's `qmake` is. Or you can add path to it in your `$PATH` in the first position (`sudo nano /etc/environment`. **Important** - in some OS /etc/environment will be empty. In this case you need to write whole `$PATH` there, like `echo PATH=\"/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin:$PATH\" > /etc/environment`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed my problem is with cmake. I noticed I get a message reading that `files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories`. Is there a way to explicitly tell cmake not look into `~/anaconda/lib` ?

Comment: `cmake` is using Qt version, that was found, using `FindQt4.cmake` (mine lies here - `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake`). Just move `qmake` path of needed version earlier in the `$PATH` variable, as it was described in the answer.

Comment: I only +1'd because I also hate cmake-this-piece-of-garbage.